# Pandas count distinct multiple columns in a dataframe and group by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I found the answer its 
test2 = test_pd.groupby(by = ['ID'])['country','color'].nunique().reset_index()

idk why this question was marked as duplicate  when the link provided by rafael didnt answer the question

I have a data frame with 3 columns:

```
   country    color    ID 
0  Germany    Red      12     
1  France     Red      13
2  US         Blue     11
3  France     Red      11
```

If I want to find out the number of distinct countries and colors per ID in SQL it would be

```
select  ID
  , count(distinct(country)) as num_countries
  , count(distinct(color)) as num_color
from table_name
group by ID;
```

The result will look like this

```
   ID    num_countries   num_color
0  12         1              1   
0  11         2              2   
0  13         1              1
```

How do I achieve the same result in Pandas?

Comment: @rafaelc OP actually wants `nunique`, which is also likely a dup. Can you find the dup for that?

Comment: @rafaelc this link you provided doesnt match my question im trying to count multiple columns seperately and group them by one column

Comment: forgot to paste it  but i figure it out .test2 = test_pd.groupby(by = ['ID'])['country','color'].nunique().reset_index()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [DataFrame.groupby.nunique](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
df_unique=df.groupby('ID')['country','color'].nunique().add_prefix('num_').reset_index()
print(df_unique)

   ID  num_country  num_color
0  11            2          2
1  12            1          1
2  13            1          1
```

Comment: But what if I just want some of the count distincts like group by age_cd but count distinct for act_type and country

Comment: please be more specific, edit your question and propose that it be reopened

Comment: Hey so I updated the question, Im basically trying to count different columns seperately not together. and group that by one field or more.

Comment: this in nunique: `df.groupby('ID').nunique().drop('ID',axis=1).reset_index()`

Comment: but that does it for all the columns what if I just wanna count two out of 20 columns by grouping it by the ID

Comment: solution updated: `df_unique=df.groupby('ID')['country','color'].nunique().add_prefix('num_').reset_index()`.please, consider accept my answer

Comment: didnt see your answer but yeah i figured it out later used this 
.test2 = test_pd.groupby(by = ['ID'])['country','color'].nunique().reset_index()

Answer (score 0):

You want `nunique()`:

```
df.groupby('age_cd', as_index=False).nunique()
```